# Model custom type as pointer or as reference?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, dereference, custom-type

In addition to pointers, C++ also provides references that behave similarly. In addition to these built-in types, it also gives the option to construct custom types that mimic this behavior.

Take these two custom types:

```cpp
class Ptr
{
private:
    int inner_;

public:
    int& operator*() { return inner_; }
    const int& operator*() const { return inner_; }
};
```

```cpp
class Ref
{
private:
    int inner_;

public:
    operator int&() { return inner_; }
    operator const int&() const { return inner_; }
};
```

These two types are used in different ways:

```
void f(const int& x);
auto r = Ref{};
auto p = Ptr{};
f(r);
f(*p);
```

These two are not equivalent but serve largely the same purpose. In the C++ standard library, example types are:

- pointer behavior: `std::optional`, `std::unique_ptr`
- reference behavior: `std::reference_wrapper`, `std::atomic`

In case we are designing a custom data type for which both pointer behavior and reference behavior are reasonable, which one should be chosen?

Comment: I came across the opinion, that signature should be `reference_type operator*() const;`, because const pointer doesn't imply const pointee. So this may also determine your choice.

Comment: `std::atomic` is different. It doesn't really wrap any type. It has its own interface and doesn't admit direct access to the underlying type, especially not in implicit conversion. `std::reference_wrapper` is also special since it is needed basically only to differentiate passing by-value and by-reference to a forwarding function which can't make that determination from value category. It has special rules in that regard for `INVOKE` expressions.

Comment: Do not use implicit conversions. They bring nothing but headache.

Comment: Nowadays there's must be a good reason to choose pointer/reference semantics over value semantics.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't allow overloading `operator.`. So, whatever you do it is not possible to achieve `ref.foo()` syntax in a generic way. `std::reference_wrapper`, for instance, uses `ref.get().foo()` syntax, which is rather convoluted.

Aside from that, implicit conversions you have in your examples are error prone and generally not desirable.

Considering these, I would design my custom class to act like a pointer, because that is fully achievable with the current language rules.

Answer (score 0):

One difference between the two models is how operators behave.

You can have `Ptr{} + Ptr{}` behave distinctly from `*Ptr{} + *Ptr{}`.

This is not true for `Ref{} + Ref{}` as here, an implicit conversion takes place and it would thus be very error prone if `operator+` on `Ref` were to behave differently than on its element type.

In general, with `Ptr{}` what is modeled is a has-a relationship: the inner value is independent from the wrapper. `Ref{}` on the contrary, models an is-a relationship: the wrapper is meant to inherently behave the same way as the inner value.